# How to Hide auto increment Id field in create page of MVC Using VB.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am new to MVC, I want to hide Id field which is auto increment so no need to show in Create New page, Here I put some code in view of create page

I am using same page for edit and create, when I click to edit Id should be show but when I click to Create New Id should not be show

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(Function(Model) Model.UserId)  
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.UserId, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.UserId, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.UserId, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
```

but It is still visible in Create page , Please help..

Comment: What exactly do you think the point is of adding a hidden field if you don't remove the existing edit field?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Actually I am using same page for edit and create, when I click to edit Id should be show but when I click to Create New Id should not be show

Comment: So you want to do one thing IF a particular condition is true and another thing otherwise. How do you usually do that?

Comment: @jmcilhinney As I said I am new to MVC , I tried to check Model is nothing or not because when you click on create new page it does not pass any value to model but if click on edit then it send selected user as model but it giving error

Comment: What error? Where? You're supposed to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem in the question but you didn't mention any such error.

Comment: Is the `Model` actually `Nothing` in the case of a new record? I don't think it is, but obviously there is something different about it.

Comment: I said if I try to check nothing value in ``` @Html.HiddenFor(Function(Model) IsNothing(Model) )``` then only it gives invalidOperationException

Comment: Yes Model is Nothing for new record , I debug that code for createNew click also and edit click also , Edit click show model which I selected.

Comment: As I said, you're supposed to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem in the question. Do that. No one should have to read the comments and pick out the relevant bits and pieces to understand the question. Provide ALL the relevant information in the question. Show us the code with the `If` statement that you know you need and, if there was an error generated, tell us exactly what and where. Don't make us drag this information out of you. ALL the relevant information means ALL the relevant information. What you tried and what happened is ALWAYS relevant.